# A particular separation example

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Q1. Does there exist a  separable Banach space  $X$  satisfying in the following property?

1- $X^*$ is non separable.

2- For every countable subset $F\subset X^*$ there exists  $0\neq x_F\in X$ such that 
$f(x_F)=0$ for all $f\in F$.

Q2. If it is impossible, what about if we replace $X$ by a separable topological vector space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ is a separable Banach space. Then $X^*$ is weak*-separable, so take a countable weak*-dense set $F$ in $X^*$. Consequently, [$F$ is total](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859334/g-is-dense-in-x-in-weak-sense-if-and-only-if-g-is-total-set), hence the only element on which all elements of $F$ simultaneously vanish is 0.

This works as long as $X$ is a locally convex space and $X^*$ is weak*-separable. Note that, by Goldstine's theorem, this will work for every $X=Y^*$, where $Y$ is a separable Banach space.

Comment: Thanks. Any example of separable locally convex space $X$ whose dual is not weak*-separable? Perhaps it serves an answer for Q2!

Comment: $\ell_1$ is separable then its second dual $X=\ell_\infty^{*}$ is weak star separable.   But its dual is not  separable any more. Right?

Comment: @AliBagheri, certainly $\ell_1^*$ is not norm-separable, however, it is weak*-separable (as is $\ell_1^{**}$). You may be interested in this paper: https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/brailey/Research_papers/Weak%20Star%20Separability.pdf